# Name of Visual Studio font and colour setting used when breaking for an unhandled exception?

Tags: visual-studio

I can't seem to figure out which font/colour setting is being used when visual studio 2019 auto-breaks for an unhandled exception in debug. As you can see, I currently have a problematic black-on-very-dark-grey.

If I change the "active statement" background the text background does change, but not to the setting I choose. Rather, it's as though it blends the chosen setting with the default black background, so choosing "white" still results in a darkish grey.

[image]

Comment: Don't you want "Current Statement" instead of "Active Statement"?

Comment: @Dai That was indeed my first thought, but it changes nothing here. This is not while debugging through line by line, it's the auto-break when you just let a program run to an unhandled exception

Comment: "Current Statement" works fine for me. [Here's white text on black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzlfl.png).

Comment: Gah, guess I'm diong a reinstall or reset and reapply every setting.